# Python Parsing nested XML and flattening the data

Tags: python, xml, xml-parsing, python-2.7, lxml

I am trying to flatten the following XML data into CSV type table data.

I could get the data in the Sal element and its attributes but I couldn't flatten SalC data to the parent sailing attributes to generate a flat table data.

I want to flatten below XML data as so that I can write to database for some further processing.

col1, col2, col3, col4, col5, col6, col6, col7, col8, col9, col10

XML Data:

```
<Sal col1="a1" col2="C" col3="12/5/2012" col4="a" col5="8" col6="True">
    <SalC col7="A" col8="1" col9="2" col10="True"/>
    <SalC col7="A1" col8="1" col9="2" col10="False"/>
    <SalC col7="B" col8="1" col9="2" col10="False"/>
    <SalC col7="C" col8="1" col9="2" col10="False"/>
    <SalC col7="D" col8="1" col9="2" col10="False"/>
    <SalC col7="E" col8="1" col9="2" col10="False"/>
    <SalC col7="E1" col8="1" col9="2" col10="False"/>
    <SalC col7="F" col8="1" col9="2" col10="False"/>
</Sal>
<Sal col1="a1" col2="C" col3="12/9/2012" col4="b" col5="8" col6="True">
    <SalC col7="A" col8="1" col9="2" col10="False"/>
    <SalC col7="B" col8="1" col9="2" col10="False"/>
    <SalC col7="C" col8="1" col9="2" col10="True"/>
    <SalC col7="D" col8="1" col9="2" col10="False"/>
    <SalC col7="E" col8="1" col9="2" col10="False"/>
</Sal>
<Sal col1="a2" col2="C" col3="12/8/2012" col4="c" col5="15" col6="True">
    <SalC col7="A" col8="1" col9="2" col10="True"/>
    <SalC col7="A1" col8="1" col9="2" col10="False"/>
    <SalC col7="B" col8="1" col9="2" col10="False"/>
    <SalC col7="C" col8="1" col9="2" col10="True"/>
    <SalC col7="D" col8="1" col9="2" col10="False"/>
    <SalC col7="E" col8="1" col9="2" col10="False"/>
    <SalC col7="E1" col8="1" col9="2" col10="True"/>
    <SalC col7="F" col8="1" col9="2" col10="False"/>
</Sal>
<Sal col1="a3" col2="C" col3="12/9/2012" col4="d" col5="8" col6="True">
    <SalC col7="A" col8="1" col9="2" col10="False"/>
    <SalC col7="B" col8="1" col9="2" col10="False"/>
    <SalC col7="C" col8="1" col9="2" col10="False"/>
    <SalC col7="D" col8="1" col9="2" col10="True"/>
    <SalC col7="E" col8="1" col9="2" col10="False"/>
</Sal>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: did you tried beautifullsoup??

Answer (score 2):

This can easily be solved using XSLT without introducing Python in your workflow, however, if you have to use Python, `lxml.etree` conveniently introduced a new class `lxml.etree.XSLT` which you can exploit to your advantage.

Assuming your `XML` data is in a file named ***`xmlfile.xml`*** the code below should work.

***xsltfile.xsl***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
        xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
        <xsl:output method="text" />
        <xsl:template match="SalC">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(../@col1,',', ../@col2,',',../@col3,',',../@col4,',',../@col5,',',../@col6,',',@col7,',',@col8,',',@col9,',',@col10)" />
        </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

---

**Example Code**

```
from lxml import etree

xsltfile = etree.XSLT(etree.parse('xsltfile.xsl'))
xmlfile = etree.parse('xmlfile.xml')
output = xsltfile(xmlfile)
print(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

`sal.attrib` is dict-like:

```
row = dict(sal.attrib)
```

`salc.attrib` is also dict-like. To "flatten" -- or rather, join -- the two dicts togther, you could use [dict.update](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.update):

```
row.update(salc.attrib)
```

Assuming each `SalC` element has `col7`, `col8`, `cal9` and `col10` attributes, you can just call `row.update(salc.attrib)` for each `salc` in `sal`:

---

```
import lxml.etree as ET
import csv

text = '''\
<root>
<Sal col1="a1" col2="C" col3="12/5/2012" col4="a" col5="8" col6="True">
    <SalC col7="A" col8="1" col9="2" col10="True"/>
...
    <SalC col7="D" col8="1" col9="2" col10="True"/>
    <SalC col7="E" col8="1" col9="2" col10="False"/>
</Sal>
</root>'''

fieldnames = ('col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6', 'col6', 'col7', 'col8', 
              'col9', 'col10')

with open('/tmp/output.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(f, fieldnames, delimiter = ',', lineterminator = '\n', )
    writer.writeheader()
    root = ET.fromstring(text)
    for sal in root.xpath('//Sal'):
        row = dict(sal.attrib)
        for salc in sal:
            row.update(salc.attrib)
            writer.writerow(row)
```

yields

```
col1,col2,col3,col4,col5,col6,col6,col7,col8,col9,col10
a1,C,12/5/2012,a,8,True,True,A,1,2,True
a1,C,12/5/2012,a,8,True,True,A1,1,2,False
a1,C,12/5/2012,a,8,True,True,B,1,2,False
...
a3,C,12/9/2012,d,8,True,True,B,1,2,False
a3,C,12/9/2012,d,8,True,True,C,1,2,False
a3,C,12/9/2012,d,8,True,True,D,1,2,True
a3,C,12/9/2012,d,8,True,True,E,1,2,False
```

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining the concept and also the answer.